# solution to an Lagrangian Inverse Problem

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inverse-function

What is the solution to the Equation
         9887.263 = (27.53–x)/ln((90–x)/62.46) ?
         Is there a real number answer to this using inverse function?
         Can you please explain the Steps...
          No Trail and Error Solution Please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "using the inverse function"?

I assume you are looking for the value of x? If you are, then

$987.26*4 = (27.53-x)/ln(90-x)$

$987.26*4*ln(90-x) = 27.53 - x $

Then exponentiate both sides and that should yield the answer? Try that and let me know if it is okay

Comment: Well.. that is not Okey Sir. If you exponentiate then it gives a situation where the question comes back to its initial position. Please tell the answer first. then discuss the steps. Thank you.